# Problem using strstr function

Tags: c

I'm having trouble using `strstr`. Here's what I have:

1. Passing character array of length 21 bytes to a function.
2. Traversing through nodes of a linked list, comparing each node's character array with the above array passed as mentioned in point 1
3. `strstr` is always returning `NULL` irrespective of any string passed
4. Let's say for example code like `strstr("hello","he")`. It should return pointer to "hello", but that never happens in my code below. It is always returns `NULL`.

Here is the code snippet of the program:

```
 void display_to_file(const char *chr,c_uint32 pos_in_list,c_uint32 line_no)
{
    NODE *search = ptrs_to_heads_of_alpha[pos_in_list];
    char *chk;
    char redundant[21]={'\0'};
    int first=1;
    uint32 count = 0;

    while((NULL!=search) && (count<21))
    {
        printf("\nsearch->arg=%s",search->arg); /*for example search->arg is "hello"*/
                  /*above statement prints "hello"-correctly*/                                        
                      /*for example chr="?he" */
                    printf("\nchr=%s",&chr[1]); /*prints "he" correctly*/
        chk=strstr(search->arg,&chr[1]); 
        if(chk != NULL) /*is always null- not known why it returns null even for valid cases*/  
            {
            printf("\nentered_\n");
            ++count;
            if(1 == first)
            {
                fprintf(op_fp,"  %s\n",search->arg);
                strcpy(redundant,search->arg);
                printf("\nop:%s\n",search->arg);
                first = 0; /*only for first node print*/
            }
            else 
            {
                if(strcmp(redundant,search->arg) == 0)/*duplicate found*/
                    --count; /*need to search for one more item*/
                else
                {
                    fprintf(op_fp,"  %s\n",search->arg);
                    strcpy(redundant,search->arg);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            printf("\nelse,else,else\n\n"); /*Always this statement is executed even
                                                                   if I passed valid arguments*/

        search=search->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: OOPS!-Added the problem statement.

Comment: What does printf("\nsearch->arg=%s",search->arg); print when you run your program?

Comment: The fact is that if your comments in the code are correct, saying that printing out `search->arg` prints out "hello" and printing out `&chr[1]` prints out "he", `strstr(search->arg, &chr[1])` **will** return a pointer to "hello". Something else is going on. Rather than `printf`-style debugging, walk through with a real debugger.

Comment: @Patrick & T.J.Crowder, When I execute those printf statments, it is displaying valid string output only(like "hello" and "he").This ensured me that there is no problem with the arguments I am passing. Even I printed string length of these two strings and which gives me correct output like(5 for "hello" and 2 for "he")

Comment: Try to replace chk=strstr(search->arg,&chr[1]); with check=strstr("hello", "he") to see if the problem is in your data structure (what I suppose) or in your binary (link/system-problem).

Comment: Hmm, this could also be a unicode/utf-8 problem, where "special" chars are hiding inside arg and chr. but you're not seeing them when printf'ing. You should really use a real debugger like T.J suggested.

Comment: make sure you include <string.h>, I have seen some compilers behaving oddly. Are you using gcc ?

Comment: @Patrick, AUZkamath, Thanks for your suggestions. I included string.h and I am using gcc. If in case, there are some special chars hiding inside, arg, the strlen should be greater than the actual characters. But strlen was returning successfully with valid value.I am also ensuring that before copying each string to each node's->char array, that char array is set to '\0' using memcpy(set End of string for all 21 bytes-as part of initialization)

Comment: it's horrible code. what should be uint32,c_uint32,NODE?

Comment: End of line is intimated by carriage-return followed by Line-feed/New-line character, if the file is being edited in DOS format. End of line is intimated by only line feed character if the file is being edited in unix mode. Cmng to actual problem, search->arg = "hello"+CR and &chr[1] = "he"+CR, thats why strstr was always returning NULL. Not sure why strlen didnot catch the CR and which led me to false assumption that, everything is fine with my datastructure!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any warning with this statement at compile time?:

```
   chk=strstr(search->arg,&chr[1]);
```

2nd argument should be const char * in strstr()
make sure this thing.

One more thing try with this statement

```
 chk=strstr(search->arg,"he");
```

one more thing check you have included string.h

```
  #include<string.h>
```

Comment: Hi Mr.32, there was a warning from compiler. Had included string.h already. Even I tried to create a temporary char array(temp) and copy contents of chr to temp and tried this statement also chk=strstr(search->arg,temp); Which still fails.I will try out what you said. Thank you

Comment: Mr 32, thanks for your time and comments. My problem got solved. Please refer to my comments inthe first row of answers, where me, patrick and others were involved. There the root cause of problem is explained

Comment: please dont say thank you & all such stuff here...if you realy like anybody's answer then just accept that answer or votes up his answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try embracing string with quotes (or another noticeable symbol), because there could be space characters, for example, which you don't see. So replace

```
printf("%s\n", some_string);
```

with

```
printf("\"%s\"\n", some_string);
```

I recommend to always use embracing with "printf-debugging". However, your problem could be somewhere else. Try to shorten your program for finding an error.

Comment: Thanks Yury- for your time and comments. My problem got solved. Please refer to my comments inthe first row of answers, where me, patrick and others were involved. There the root cause of problem is explained